# Synonym for "Love handles" (flanks)

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym for this term? I heard it on an US TV show. It refers to the flanks. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome Carolina!  Can you please share the results of your research?

Comment: You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas here we’re more intended “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”

Comment: [love handles](http://thesaurus.com/browse/love%20handles)

Comment: What about "[Terryfold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gfw4yxn_kPQ)"?

Answer (score 2):

Love Handle is just a colloquialism for excess fat on the abdominal part, usually the sides of the waistline. 
I don't think there is a one word synonym for it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is "Middle-age spread" which I hadn't heard about, but I've definitely heard "spare tire" being used.

For more, see http://thesaurus.com/browse/love-handles

"spare tire"
"bulging wasteline"
"hate handles"
"keg"
"flab"
"fat"

Comment: I don't know what the general way of answering questions like this should be on this SE subsite... It seems quick google searches are usually the quickest for the 'thesaurus' questions. =/

Comment: +1 for **spare tyre**. Haven’t heard any of the others used (well, I have heard of bulging wastelines, kegs, flab, and fat, of course—but not used to refer to this particular phenomenon).

Comment: @Spork See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @TrevorD I clicked... and read... but this is generic SE stuff. Is all there is to do with the 'thesaurus' questions to downvote it?

Comment: @Spork Sorry, didn't know it was generic stuff - I don't use any other SE sites. This [page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions questioners using dictionaries & thesaurus *before asking* questions (see bottom section). Don't know if that is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

the technical (perhaps the most neutral) term is ***central obesity***.

Some mischievous expressions include

***bay window***

***muffin top***

Comment: +1 for **muffin top**. Never heard ‘bay window’ before (and I’m not sure I think it’s a very well-chosen image, either).